# RadioButton Style, also CheckBox Style

Tags: android, android-widget

My app uses the default RadioButtons and default CheckBox style.  That means for RadioButtons the display includes a small round icon which turns green when you click it, followed by the text to the right of it.  For CheckBoxes, there's a small square that holds a green check icon when you click it, followed by the text to the right of it.

Is it possible to easily change this?  I'd like the RadioButtons and CheckBoxes to look like regular Buttons (no round or square icon) and then then turn a different color when they are checked.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html).